# Jsonstatdataset rename

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I am trying to read a table from the Central Statistics Office for Ireland. I am reading it into a collection and successfully displaying the first dataset

```
dataset = collection.dataset(0)
print(dataset)
```

which returns:

```
name:   'dataset'
label:  'Residential Property Price Index'
source: 'Residential Property Price Index'
size: 16800
+-----+--------------+--------------+------+--------+
| pos | id           | label        | size | role   |
+-----+--------------+--------------+------+--------+
| 0   | STATISTIC    | STATISTIC    | 4    | metric |
| 1   | TLIST(M1)    | TLIST(M1)    | 210  | time   |
| 2   | C02803V03373 | C02803V03373 | 20   |        |
+-----+--------------+--------------+------+--------+
```

I can print out each of the dimensions e.g.

```
print(dataset.dimension('STATISTIC'))
print(dataset.dimension('TLIST(M1)'))
print(dataset.dimension('C02803V03373'))
```

The first dimension is the statistic type, the second is the quarter year and the last is the region of the country. My difficulty though is, when I try to retreive a particular statistic for a particular quarter for a particular region I get an error:

```
dataset.data(STATISTIC='HPM09C04', TLIST(M1)='2022M06'  ,C02803V03373='05')
dataset.data(STATISTIC='HPM09C04', TLIST(M1)='2022M06'  ,C02803V03373='05')
                                       ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

When "TLIST(M1)" used to be called "QUARTER" this worked fine but clearly the name containing parenthesis is causing an issue. If I do not specify a particular quarter, I get the first quarter.

So my question is, is there a way to reference a particular quarter while keeping the name as 'TLIST(M1)' or failing that a way to rename it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you importing the data? You say, "I am reading it into a collection" -- what does your code to do that look like?

Comment: So I am using a Jupyter notebook and following the method outlined in this repository https://github.com/virtualarchitectures/CSO_Ireland_JSONStat4Py/blob/master/CSO_Ireland_JSONStat4Py.ipynb    Apologies cannot add the individual lines to this comment with proper formatting but there are only a few preceding steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it this way:

```
import jsonstat
dataset = jsonstat.from_file('HPM06.20220902T150925.json')
args={'STATISTIC':'HPM09C04', 'TLIST(M1)':'2022M06'  ,'C02803V03373':'05'}          
answer = dataset.data(**args)
print(answer)
# prints  JsonStatValue(idx=16783, value=11.8, status=None)
```

I used jsonstat, installed via `pip install jsonstat.py` (yes, including the ".py"). The data is from https://www.cso.ie/en/index.html , search for "Residential Property Price Index" and download the .json file.